# Proving that if matrix A is similar to B, A^n is similar to B^n.

Tags: linear-algebra

#### Matrix A is similar to matrix B <=> B=S$^-$$^1$AS

**Prove that if A is similar to matrix B => A$^n$ is also similar to to B$^n$. (n is a member of ℤ).**

Without thinking too much, the first idea that came into my mind was proof by induction.

for n=1: B=S$^-$$^1$AS

for n=k: B$^k$=S$^-$$^1$A$^k$S

for n=k+1: B$^k$$^+$$^1$=S$^-$$^1$A$^k$$^+$$^1$S

B$^k$B=S$^-$$^1$A$^k$AS

B$^k$B=S$^-$$^1$A$^k$SS$^-$$^1$AS

I'm not sure how to decompose the proof at this point. I could say that due to our inductive assumption, B$^k$ = S$^-$$^1$A$^k$S is sure to be a true statement. What is left is B=S$^-$$^1$AS, which is also true given the very first assumption. But I don't think this is the right way to decompose the proof. Can anyone help me?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
S^{-1} A^{n} S
=
S^{-1} A S S^{-1} A S \cdots S^{-1} A S
=
B^{n}.
$$

Or, proceeding by induction, assume $B^{k} = S^{-1} A^{k} S$, and get
$$
B^{k+1}
=
B^{k} B
=
S^{-1} A^{k} S S^{-1} A S
=
S^{-1} A^{k+1} S.
$$

Answer (score 1):

This is a standard manipulation.  Think about going in both directions in this equation: $$\begin{align}
    B \cdot B = (S^{-1}AS) \cdot (S^{-1}AS) = S^{-1}A(S S^{-1})AS = S^{-1}A^2 S
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

wait but why do you assume that the invertible matrix S in $B = (S^{-1})A(S)$ and the one in $B^k = (S^{-1})A^k(S)$ is the same?? How are they the same? Is there an implicit assumption I am not understanding?